# QBluetooth BLE advertising does not work on ubuntu (BlueZ)

Tags: linux, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, qtbluetooth

I tried to advertise a BluetoothLE service using Qt today. I started by testing the [Bluetooth Low Energy Heart Rate Server Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-heartrate-server-example.html) and it worked just fine on my Android phone. On my Ubuntu 18.04 Laptop though, I could not get it to work.

When I run the example as root, I get the error `qt.bluetooth.bluez: received advertising error`.
After enabling debug messages, I got this log:

```
qt.bluetooth: Using BlueZ kernel ATT interface
qt.bluetooth.bluez: Bluez 5 detected.
qt.bluetooth.bluez: Starting to advertise
qt.bluetooth.bluez: sending command; ogf: 8 ocf: 7
qt.bluetooth.bluez: command sent successfully
qt.bluetooth.bluez: HCI event triggered, type: e
qt.bluetooth.bluez: command 7 failed with status 12
qt.bluetooth.bluez: reading power level failed, leaving it out of the advertising data
qt.bluetooth.bluez: advertising parameters: "000800080000000000000000000700"
qt.bluetooth.bluez: advertising data: "18020106100948656172745261746553657276657203030d1800000000000000"
qt.bluetooth.bluez: scan response data: "15100948656172745261746553657276657203030d1800000000000000000000"
qt.bluetooth.bluez: sending command; ogf: 8 ocf: 10
qt.bluetooth.bluez: command sent successfully
qt.bluetooth.bluez: HCI event triggered, type: e
qt.bluetooth.bluez: command 10 failed with status 12
qt.bluetooth.bluez: Advertising disable failed, ignoring
qt.bluetooth.bluez: sending command; ogf: 8 ocf: 6
qt.bluetooth.bluez: command sent successfully
qt.bluetooth.bluez: HCI event triggered, type: e
qt.bluetooth.bluez: command 6 failed with status 12
qt.bluetooth.bluez: received advertising error
```

Does anybody know what all these error messages mean?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue when attempting to use https://github.com/nymea/nymea-networkmanager on Intel NUC devices. Any time it attempted to issue Bluetooth LE commands I would see 'command disallowed' via btmon.

Issuing `hcitool cmd 0x03 0x000` would reset the device and get it to start advertising, but it would soon crash again right after. It appears that a lot of bluetooth changes were introduced in the 4.19 kernel and have been causing issues with LE system calls.

I was able to get it to work by using an older Ubuntu version with 4.15 kernel.

More details here
https://github.com/nymea/nymea-networkmanager/issues/46

Comment: Hi Nathan, I actually got it to work by upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 which come with a 5.X Kernel :)